# PC not detecting mouse or keyboard in OS or BIOS

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse

I was hoping someone could provide some insight on this strange issue?
After rebooting my mice and keyboard have stopped functioning both in Windows and in the boot screens. I have tried the following steps to troubleshoot but have had no luck. Please note that the monitor is working.

- Restarted
- Cycled power (removed power cord and powered on)
- Changed ports
- Tested with other mice/keyboards
- Plugged the same setup into a laptop where the devices worked perfectly
- removed CMOS
- Tested other USB devices. I was able to change RGB via a USB receiver.
- Tested power on ports, worked fine and powered up my phone/tablet

Is there something else that I should try? I have searched online but everyone is saying to test in BIOS or reinstall the MB USB drivers which is impossible if I cant get past the login screen.

Comment: Any chance your motherboard has a PS/2 port and you can scrounge up a PS/2 keyboard somewhere?

Comment: great idea! I will grab one tomorrow from the office and provide an update.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an issue with your computer, for sure.

If it's a desktop, open it up and see if you can reset the CMOS settings back to the default, and try again. While you're in there, look for capacitors that look like they are ready to explode (bulging).

Make sure your keyboard/mouse are plugged into USB 2 ports, not USB 3. Do they work when you plug them into a USB hub, then the hub into the computer?

If you're on a laptop, try the HP method of clearing settings: press and hold the power button for 2 minutes, then try opening it.

Failing all this, get the motherboard model and a flash drive. Go to another computer, check for firmware for your motherboard, and copy it to your FAT32-formatted flash drive. Try booting with the flash drive plugged in, and see if it auto-detects the new firmware and installs it.

If that still doesn't work, then it is time to either replace the motherboard/computer, or take it to a repair shop.